# Firefox crashes with mulitple Uploadify JQuery browse buttons and ajax

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, uploadify

I'm using four JQuery Uploadify browse buttons on a page that's calling the Uploadify code/buttons through Ajax. We have a javascript function called from onComplete which refreshes the Ajax page. The problem we're encountering is that when you start uploading one file, if you click browse to upload another file, Firefox will crash when selecting the second file.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was to just hide the other buttons while an upload is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you wouldn't use the built-in [multiple-file upload functionality](http://www.uploadify.com/demo/) that Uploadify allows?  In most cases it's as simple as setting:

```
'multi' : true
```

Comment: Yes, because we need different types of documents, such as one upload button for resumes, another for cover letters, etc.